# Can't send email using MimeKit

Tags: c#, email-attachments, mimekit

I am following [this article](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-send-email/) to send email using Mimekit. I have two controllers one is Home Controller and the other is BlogData Controller. Problem is when I try and send email in the BlogData Controller, it's able to send the email fine. But in the Home Controller, Index action method when I try to send an email, it says:

> Mail Delivery Subsystem Address not found The response from the remote server was: 511 sorry, no mailbox here by that name (#5.1.1 - chkuser)

In my app settings here is the config:

```
"EmailConfiguration": {
    "From": "abcxyz1234@gmail.com",
    "SmtpServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 465,
    "Username": "abcxyz1234@gmail.com",
    "Password": "mmzqygciqxzrbrbh" // This password was generated by gmail from the above article.
  },
```

Here is the method within Home Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SendEmail([Bind("Name,Email,Message")] SingleEmailMessage emailMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                var files = Request.Form.Files.Any() ? Request.Form.Files : new FormFileCollection();
                Message m = new Message(new List<string> { "ans1234@gamil.com" }, "Someone messaged from KGS", string.Format("Name: {0}, Email: {1}, Message: {2}", emailMessage.Name, emailMessage.Email, emailMessage.Message), files);
                _emailSender.SendEmailWithAttchmentsAsync(m);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { data = "Error" });
            }
            return Json(new { data = "DONE" });
        }
```

In the email sender class this is the code (it's the same exact code in the article above). The problem is when I send from Home Controller it doesn't work. But In BlogData Controller, it's able to send the mail fine. I can't understand.

```
 private MimeMessage CreateEmailWithAttachment(Message message)
        {
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_emailConfig.From));
            emailMessage.To.AddRange(message.To);
            emailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder { HtmlBody = string.Format("<h2 style='color:red;'>{0}</h2>", message.Content) };
            if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Any())
            {
                byte[] fileBytes;
                foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        attachment.CopyTo(ms);
                        fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                    bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(attachment.FileName, fileBytes, ContentType.Parse(attachment.ContentType));
                }
            }
            emailMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
            return emailMessage;
        }

private async Task SendAsync(MimeMessage mailMessage)
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    await client.ConnectAsync(_emailConfig.SmtpServer, _emailConfig.Port, true);
                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                    await client.AuthenticateAsync(_emailConfig.UserName, _emailConfig.Password);
                    await client.SendAsync(mailMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //log an error message or throw an exception or both.

                }
                finally
                {
                    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                    client.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help with something? https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/#mailkit

Comment: Thank you, I changed to using the Smtp client and it works fine.